# Why does the behavior of mkdir differs on different Linux distros?

Tags: c++, system

I was trying to create folders named 1 2 3 4, using the C++ program below. I can successfully achieve that in **RHEL**.
However it created a folder named {1..4} in **ubuntu 13.10**.

Why does this happen? Thank you for helping me!

```
    #include <cstdlib>

    int main()
    {
        std::system("mkdir {1..4}");
    }
```

It's a part of CPP unit test in our product. Yes, it's ugly. But I am afraid very few thing can be done in this situation.

You are right.
In RHEL,
    sh -c 'echo {1..4}'
    1 2 3 4

In Ubuntu
    sh -c 'echo {1..4}'
    {1..4}

So I use the program below instead. It works!
   #include

```
int main()
{
    std::system("bash -c 'mkdir {1..4}'");
}
```

seems system use sh by default....Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Most likely the behavior of `mkdir` is different between the two systems. Did you check the man pages?

Comment: Also, are you running the same shell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit of terminology: Linux has [directories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_%28computing%29) in its [file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system), not "folders" (folders may appear visually on the desktop, but that is a desktop detail).

You don't need to use [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) (which is running `sh` not `bash`!). 
And POSIX `sh` don't know the `{1..4}` notation, hence the `{1..4}` string is passed *verbatim* to `/bin/mkdir` command (see [mkdir(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkdir.1.html) ...).

Run

```
 sh -c 'echo {1..4}'
```

to test that `sh` don't understand the `{1..4}` notation.

(so it is a bug in your old RHEL, where perhaps `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash` while on Debian and Ubuntu it is a symlink to the more Posix compliant and faster `/bin/dash`)

Just use the [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) syscall and code

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
   for (int i=1; i<=4; i++) {
      char buf[8];
      snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", i);
      if (mkdir(buf, 0755))
        { perror("mkdir"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
   }
}
```

I hope you don't want to create a *single* directory named `1 2 3 4`. It is possible and easy, but it really is poor taste. For your mental safety, use only letters, digits and underscores `_` in directory names.

I am using [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) to convert an int to a character buffer. With [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) you could use [std::to_string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) and [c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) ...

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)...

Using the `mkdir(2)` syscall instead of going thru a command invoked by `system(3)` has several important advantages:

- it is much faster, you don't need to [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) a `/bin/sh -c` shell like `system(3)` should do.
- it uses much less resources, since no additional process is `fork`-ed, so your program will still run when you have reached your limits (see [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) ...)
- it is more reliable. Should `mkdir(2)` fail you could (and should) handle the failure nicely. See [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) ....

Comment: `sh -c 'echo {1..4}'` and the C call to std::system create 4 folders for me on Ubuntu 12.04. Though using /bin/dash behaves as you described. Any insight into if this was something that changed between Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.10? Or how Vincent got into this position?

Comment: @AffluentOwl: I don't have Ubuntu at the moment (just Mint & Debian), but I might guess that `dash` has improved...